# which() with objects of type character

Tags: r, xts

I have a questions that might be too basic, but here it is...

I want to extract monthly data from a dataset like this:

```
    Date     Obs
1 2001-01-01 120
2 2001-01-02 100
3 2001-01-03 150
4 2001-01-04 175
5 2001-01-05 121
6 2001-01-06 100
```

I just want to get the rows from the data where I have a certain month(e.g. January), this works perfectly:

```
output=which(strftime(dataset[,1],"%m")=="01",dataset[,1])
```

However when I try to create a loop to go through all the months using a variable that is declared has character it doesn't work and I only get "FALSE".

```
value=as.character(k)
output=which(strftime(dataset[,1],"%m")==value,dataset[,1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do *not* parse dates as strings. That is too error prone. Parse dates as dates, and do logical comparisons on them.

Here is one approach, creating January to March data and sub-setting February based on a comparison:

```
R> output <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"), by=7, length=10), 
+                       value=cumsum(runif(10)*100))
R> output
         date     value
1  2011-01-01   8.29916
2  2011-01-08  44.82950
3  2011-01-15  72.08662
4  2011-01-22 134.19277
5  2011-01-29 221.67744
6  2011-02-05 245.77195
7  2011-02-12 314.82081
8  2011-02-19 396.34661
9  2011-02-26 437.14286
10 2011-03-05 442.41321
R> output[ output[,"date"] >= as.Date("2011-02-01") & 
+          output[,"date"] <= as.Date("2011-02-28"), ]
        date   value
6 2011-02-05 245.772
7 2011-02-12 314.821
8 2011-02-19 396.347
9 2011-02-26 437.143
R>
```

Another approach uses the xts package:

```
R> oo <- xts(output[,"value"], order.by=output[,"date"])
R> oo
                [,1]
2011-01-01   8.29916
2011-01-08  44.82950
2011-01-15  72.08662
2011-01-22 134.19277
2011-01-29 221.67744
2011-02-05 245.77195
2011-02-12 314.82081
2011-02-19 396.34661
2011-02-26 437.14286
2011-03-05 442.41321
R> oo["2011-02-01::2011-02-28"]
               [,1]                 
2011-02-05 245.772
2011-02-12 314.821
2011-02-19 396.347
2011-02-26 437.143
R>
```

as xts has convenient date parsing for the index; see the package documentation for details.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming `k` is an integer in `1:12`. I suspect you may be better off using abbreviated month names:

```
value <- month.abb[k]
output <- which(strftime(dataset[,1],"%b")==value,dataset[,1])
```

The reason you way isn't working is because the month number is zero-padded and `"1" != "01"`.

Comment: yes it is (1 to 12), I forgot it. a really basic mistake, i did forgot that i have 01 to 12 and not 1 to 12. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use dates as dates with `POSIXlt()$mon`

```
as.POSIXlt(output$date)$mon  # Note that Jan = 0 and Feb=1
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2
```

There are several other packages such as chron, lubridate and gdata that provide date handling functions. I found the functions in lubridate particularly intuitive and less prone to errors in my clumsy hands.

Comment: +1 -- That's a good comment, but the one thing I *hate* about the POSIX month representation is the 0 to 11 range. Fine at the C programming level, not so fine up in R.